# Django. Static files not load

Tags: django

I encountered such a problem, static files (pictures) are not loading in my Django project.

The most amazing thing is that I did not change anything, just yesterday, everything worked, and today the pictures are refusing to load.

If I follow a direct link to an object, the picture is and opens. However, if you register it in a CSS file, the path to the image is crossed out, and the inscription in the browser debugger "invalid property value"

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, but it works. Maybe someone will be useful. The graphic files that were the background were not loaded.
The background was assigned through CSS according to this principle:

```
#showcase-inner {
  background: url(../img/flowers.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed/cover;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 350px; }
```

I repeat. Previously, everything worked, at what point everything went wrong, I did not follow. But when I changed CSS, the graphics started loading:

```
#showcase-inner {
  background-size: cover cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  background-image: url(../img/building.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 350px; }
```

Comment: It turns out the error is not so much in static files as in CSS